# Open and show internationalized HTML resource in an activity

Tags: android, resources

I want to make language-specific help files in HTML and view them using the browser.
As first version I put the english version in res/raw (There seems to be no html- or doc-directory).
To start the browser I found:

```
        String URL = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.help;
        Uri u = Uri.parse(URL);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, u);
        startActivity(intent);
```

But it always throws an ApplicationNotFound-Exception.

Looking at the variables I can see that URL is:

```
         android.resource://[PACKAGE_NAME]/[NUMBER]
```

and that is also the content of u. Uri.parse just copies the given string.

My questions:

What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way?
Would the system find a file in res/raw-de?

Answer (score 2):

You can open a html page from "Assets" folder using the following

```
//help_activity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/helpwebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

In a resource file, for e.g., in strings.xml. "file:///android_asset" corresponds to "Assets" folder in Android project.

```
<string name="help_url">file:///android_asset/help/index_de.html</string>
```

//Code for HelpActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class HelpActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.help_activity);
        WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.helpwebview);

        WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        browser.loadUrl(getString(R.string.help_url));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will do it this way!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to load WebView directly with the resource file.

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html_file.html");
```

Make sure you put all your files in **Assets** folder

Comment: Do I have to use the asset-directory?

Comment: But then I have to select the correct file for the given language. And I have to pop up a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it:

```
String summary = readRawTextFile(this,R.raw.help);
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL (null,summary, "text/html","UTF-8" ,null);
```